# Microsoft CNTK Automatic Differentiation

Tags: cntk, autodiff

According to Microsoft, CNTK includes automatic differentiation. For better understanding the source (which I've successfully built) I'd like to know which C++ classes implement AD and how it is implemented in CNTK?

Answer (score 3):

CNTK class `Function` implements the AD (via [Gradients](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/0ffdcf7f1d7e2ff58b4c41e74a6193accd6f78ae/Source/CNTKv2LibraryDll/Function.cpp) method, to be precise). Neural networks are represented as multiple `Function` compositions like *g(f(x))*. Then derivative of function *g* is computed with respect to *f* like this:

[image: derivative]